# How to change text of child view onclick of recycler view?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have it clicked and it gets up to it and shows the right getText() method but the setText method is not working...

```
userAdapter.setOnEntryClickListener(new UserAdapter.OnEntryClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onEntryClick(View view, int position) {
                DatabaseUser user = dbUsersList.get(position);
                    TextView clickedView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userAdapterFollowBtn);
                if(view == clickedView) {
                    if (clickedView.getText().equals("following")) {

                        Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, " THE CLICK VIEW IS " + clickedView.getText());
                        //APPLY Following
                        String txtFollow = "follow";
                        clickedView.setText(txtFollow);
                        if (user.getIsChanged() == 0) {
                            user.setIsChanged(1);
                        } else {
                            user.setIsChanged(0);
                        }
                        user.setIsType(3);
                        db.updateFollow(user);

                        userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    } else {

                        clickedView.setText("following");
                        if (user.getIsChanged() == 0) {
                            user.setIsChanged(1);
                        } else {
                            user.setIsChanged(0);
                        }
                        user.setIsType(0);
                        db.updateFollow(user);

                        userAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), user.getUsername() + " is selected!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    takeToUserProfile(dbUsersList.get(position));
                }
            }
        });
```

Here is the adapter class:

```
public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    private List<DatabaseUser> dbUsersList, followingList;
    private DatabaseHelper db;
    private Context context;
    private Typeface typeFace, italicTypeface, boldTypeface;


    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public TextView userAdapterUsername, userAdapterFollowBtn;
        public ImageView userAdapterUserPicture;


        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
            userAdapterUsername = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userAdapterUsername);
            userAdapterFollowBtn = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.userAdapterFollowBtn);
            userAdapterUserPicture = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.userAdapterUserPicture);
            Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "IN MY VIEW HOLDER");

            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            userAdapterFollowBtn.setOnClickListener(this);

        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mOnEntryClickListener != null) {
                Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "IN On click");
                mOnEntryClickListener.onEntryClick(v, getAdapterPosition());


            }
        }
    }
    private static OnEntryClickListener mOnEntryClickListener;

    public interface OnEntryClickListener {
        void onEntryClick(View view, int position);
    }

    public void setOnEntryClickListener(OnEntryClickListener onEntryClickListener) {
        mOnEntryClickListener = onEntryClickListener;
    }


    public UserAdapter(Context mContext, List<DatabaseUser> usersList, List<DatabaseUser> passedFollowing, Typeface myTypeface, Typeface myTypefaceItalic, Typeface myTypefaceBold) {
        context = mContext;
        dbUsersList = usersList;
        followingList = passedFollowing;
        typeFace = myTypeface;
        italicTypeface = myTypefaceItalic;
        boldTypeface = myTypefaceBold;
        Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "IN MY User ADAPTER CONSTRUCTOR");
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.follow_item, parent, false);
        Log.d(Constants.DEBUG, "RETURN ITEM VIEW HOLDER");


        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final MyViewHolder holder, int position) {


         DatabaseUser user = dbUsersList.get(position);


        holder.userAdapterUsername.setTypeface(boldTypeface);

        holder.userAdapterUsername.setText(user.getUsername());

        final int pos = getItemViewType(position);
        //TODO Create pic link

        if(containsId(dbUsersList.get(pos), followingList)) {
            //Then show following
            holder.userAdapterFollowBtn.setText("following");


        } else {
            //show follow
            holder.userAdapterFollowBtn.setText("follow");
        }



        String userspic = dbUsersList.get(pos).getPicture();
        if(userspic == null) {
            //SET DEFAULT OR PUT DEFAULT IN XML AND DO NOTHING IT SHOULD SHOW DEFAULT PIC
        } else {
            //TODO setupUser Pic
            String img1 = "http://www.hindustantimes.com/Images/popup/2015/6/kungfu2.jpg";
            Picasso.with(context).load(img1).transform(new RoundedTransformation()).into(holder.userAdapterUserPicture);

        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dbUsersList.size();
    }

    public static boolean containsId(DatabaseUser currentUser, List<DatabaseUser> list) {
        for (DatabaseUser object : list) {
            if (currentUser.getUserId().equals(object.getUserId())) {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What ended up being the problem is that I had passed in the followingList, so I never re-called to grab the new following from the db on update. The update was happening I just had to re-grab the followingList from the db to have an updated list to check against like so in a new method that was passing the list back to the contains method.

```
 db.grabFollowersList();
```

Answer (score 1):

your `dbUsersList` is not updating. please check your  user object in `dbUsersList` after notify data set change.

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean? dbUsersList updates correctly, the only issue I am having with this is the setText method does not get called, which I do not understand why or what I am doing wrong when trying to set the text of the view, if I am somehow suppose to refresh the child button view

Comment: Debug it and check

Comment: Good call, what was happening was completely different but you got me thinking!